# split column value of a table and skip some words

Tags: sql, oracle, split, string-parsing

Hil All,

I have a table , count is about 200M. It has a column which contains data separated by '~'. I want to parse it.

e.g:

```
Column1
A~B~C~D~E~F

Result :
Column_new1
A~C~E
```

I just want to skip 2,4,6,n th. words. I don't want plsql. I need sql query. And table is very big,I also need performance.

I use substr,instr functions and I can parse. But it runs really slowly..

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your 200M rows should have been stored as 600M rows and that would still be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after performance then use the `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(column1, 1,      p1 - 1 ) || '~' ||
       SUBSTR(column1, p2 + 1, p3 - p2 - 1) || '~' ||
       SUBSTR(column1, p4 + 1, p5 - p4 - 1) AS column1_new
FROM   (
  SELECT column1,
         INSTR(column1, '~', 1, 1) AS p1,
         INSTR(column1, '~', 1, 2) AS p2,
         INSTR(column1, '~', 1, 3) AS p3,
         INSTR(column1, '~', 1, 4) AS p4,
         INSTR(column1, '~', 1, 5) AS p5
  FROM   table_name
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (column1) AS
SELECT 'A~B~C~D~E~F' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COLUMN1_NEW |
> | --- |
> | A~C~E |

---

If you want a shorter query then you can use regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '([^~]+)~[^~]+~([^~]+)~[^~]+~([^~]+).*', '\1~\2~\3' )
         AS column1_new
FROM   table_name;
```

However, you will find that performance is likely to be an order of magnitude worse than simple string functions.

---

Another alternative would be to generate a materialized view.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=468ee97564472c285f9662fef59d896f)*

Comment: I parsed same. It is very slowly. I think we have no alternatives?

Comment: @user3646666 That will likely be as-fast or faster than anything else. If you want to use it repeatedly then, as I mention at the end, you can create a materialized view once and use that for future queries. Or you can redesign your table to not store delimited strings and store the values in separate columns.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider other alternatives that you said.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular expressions option. Looks *nice*, isn't PL/SQL, works OK (for 2 rows). I'm afraid that *anything* will run slow for 200 million rows.

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2     (select 1, 'A~B~C~D~E~F' from dual union all
  3      select 2, 'M~N~O~P~Q-R' from dual
  4     )
  5  select id,
  6         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 1) || '~' ||
  7         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 3) || '~' ||
  8         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 5) result
  9  from test;

        ID RESULT
---------- -----------------------------------
         1 A~C~E
         2 M~O~Q

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks. But you are right, it is very slowy